# Partially defined boolean function

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, network-flow, boolean-algebra

Consider a Boolean function $f(x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{n})$. The value of $f$ is defined on some set of inputs, and some inputs are undefined (let us label undefined value with $?$). It is possible to set $f$'s value on some inputs, no matter if they were initially defined.

The problem is to set some of the inputs such that:

- all initially undefined inputs become defined (i. e. no $?$ in function's truth table);
- $f$ is monotone in the common sense.

The optimization part is to use the minimum possible assignments. How can one find an optimal way to do so in the time $\mathcal{O}\left(p(n) \left( 2^{n} \right)^{2} \right)$, where $p(n)$ is polynomial?

Comment: Can you share any context where you encountered this task and what makes you ask about that specific running time?  (As opposed to, say, $O(p(n) 2^n)$ or $O(p(n) 2^{3n})$ or $2^{O(n)}$?)

Comment: @D.W. This is somehow related to flows in networks (e. g. max flow problem). I thought about creating network with vertices for every input (so we have $2^{n}$ vertices), but I have no idea how to introduce edges in the desired network, because connecting every pair of inputs according to partial order leads to exponential edge count.